# IE8 documentMode always 'quirk mode'

Tags: javascript, document, mode

I'm trying to print a message to the user when he is using an IE version bellow IE8. To test it I enabled the Document Mode 8. But when I ask for the Document Mode in javascript I always receive the 'quirk mode: 5'

```
 document.documentMode;
```

Does anyone know why?

Here is the beginning of my specification:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
   <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
   ...
```

**SOLVED:**

I used the user-agent nevertheless and checked for the 'trident/4.0' tag which is displayed only in IE8

Comment: doesn't IE switch to quirks mode if it feels that the markup isn't valid?

Comment: @GungFoo — No. It only cares about the Doctype and X-UA-Compatible.

Comment: What DocType haveyou specified?

Comment: updated the doctype specification

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things that can force IE into QuirksMode the most obvious two are

1. A Missing, malformed or dated Doctype see the [table near the bottom of this page for a comprehensive guide to which doctypes will trigger quirksmode](http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/)
2. Anything on the page before the DocType, IE insist on the DocType being the absolute first thing to appear in the file or it assumes no DocType and revers to QuirksMode

Answer (score 0):

Use this meta tag in your page head section...

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
```

It'll finalized your document mode.

Comment: If your concern is displaying a message if user accessing your site below IE8 version, then use the smartest way like by user-agent. Every browser has there unique user-agent string, so display your message based on user-agent string. I think it is more easier the finding and finalizing doc mode.

Comment: The two points mentioned by @Simon are also correct. So verify it from your page source. Otherwise I didn't see anything wrong with the setup.